# How do I train model using optimised weights?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm working on the optimization of parameter of model. Broadly, I trained the weights of a model with some structure. I now use this weights to train another model of exact same structure. But I am not able to get the same accuracy, no where near the same in the first epoch.

The following piece of code explains the whole problem.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.datasets import imdb

# set parameters:
max_features = 5000
maxlen = 400
batch_size = 32
embedding_dims = 50
filters = 250
kernel_size = 3
hidden_dims = 250

print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(len(x_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(x_test), 'test sequences')

print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()

# we start off with an efficient embedding layer which maps
# our vocab indices into embedding_dims dimensions
model.add(Embedding(max_features,
                    embedding_dims,
                    input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# we add a Convolution1D, which will learn filters
# word group filters of size filter_length:
model.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid',    activation='relu', strides=1))
# we use max pooling:
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

# We add a vanilla hidden layer:
model.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# We project onto a single unit output layer, and squash it with a sigmoid:
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mse',Optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=50, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

# Extraction of weights
con_weight=model.layers[2].get_weights()[0]
con_bias=model.layers[2].get_weights()[1]

mid_weight=model.layers[4].get_weights()[0]
mid_bias=model.layers[4].get_weights()[1]

pl_weight=model.layers[7].get_weights()[0]
pl_bias=model.layers[7].get_weights()[1]
```

## Using weights to train another model

```
model1 = Sequential()

# we start off with an efficient embedding layer which maps
# our vocab indices into embedding_dims dimensions
model1.add(Embedding(max_features,
                    embedding_dims,
                    input_length=maxlen))
model1.add(Dropout(0.2))

# we add a Convolution1D, which will learn filters
# word group filters of size filter_length:
model1.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid',activation='relu', strides=1,weights=[con_weight,con_bias]))
# we use max pooling:
model1.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

# We add a vanilla hidden layer:
model1.add(Dense(hidden_dims,weights=[mid_weight,mid_bias]))
model1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model1.add(Activation('relu'))

# We project onto a single unit output layer, and squash it with a sigmoid:
model1.add(Dense(1,weights=[pl_weight,pl_bias]))
model1.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model1.trainable=False
model1.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1,
validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embeddings do have weights, and you're forgetting them.

But your models are identical, just:

```
model1.set_weights(model.get_weights())
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. How can I set embedding layer to be static?

Comment: Before `compile`, `model.layers[0].trainable=False`. But do you have trained weights for them? If you don't, better let them trainable.

Comment: Actually I am optimising weights with some other algorithm, though highly unsucessful till now.